# How to watch post data

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, payment-processing

I have implemented paypal button in my asp.net app. When buttons redirect me to paypal and when I pay service paypal redirect me to one of my pages where I need to get data retrived from paypal. I tried to se that data in firebug but I can't find anything. Is there any way to watch received data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com). It allows you to view HTTP traffic including headers.

**Edit**
Description from the website:

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which
>   logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your
>   computer and the Internet. Fiddler
>   allows you to inspect all HTTP(S)
>   traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle"
>   with incoming or outgoing data.
>   Fiddler includes a powerful
>   event-based scripting subsystem, and
>   can be extended using any .NET
>   language.
>
> Fiddler is freeware and can debug
>   traffic from virtually any
>   application, including Internet
>   Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, and
>   thousands more.

Comment: +1. I always turn to one of: Firebug, Fiddler, then Wireshark when all else fails.

Answer (score 5):

When all else fails use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). I'm also a fan of [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) and [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/).

Comment: *Tamper Data* is horrible. When enabled it's enabled globally so to use it you need to close all tabs which perform regular requests.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I would recommend using multiple profiles in Firefox. I have a “dev” profile that I use for special times such as when I need to use tamper data. Once you have the profile setup you can create a shortcut like `firefox -P dev --no-remote` to launch it.

Comment: In a way, but I find it quite handy to have some annoying but useful add-ons available on demand w/o having to deal with them installed in my normal profile.

Answer (score 1):

Somethimes I've used the **Developer Toolbar of IE**... it's very simple... 
Press F12 and go to the Tab **Networking** then Start Capturing and when finished you have all data in the Result View. double click on a single request and you get it!

Otherwise the FireBug tools it's quite good!